# How do I seed an Azure File Share from an Azure Blob (classic)?

Tags: azure, azure-files

We want to use Azure File Shares and File Sync as a backup system for our file server.  We already have 1:1 file backups a week old sitting in a blob in Azure.  Is there any way to copy that data including modify and creation date to the file share?  I have Azure Storage Explorer installed but it doesn't give me a paste option when I navigate to the file share.  If I use download it will strip all creation and modify dates.

Would this even work to seed our file share?  Will file sync want to overwrite everything if security info has changed?

Comment: Going through adding the server endpoint there are two sync options and the 2nd one is required if the share was seeded from a databox.  It talks about updating security metadata, etc.  I'll try downloading some files using an Azure VM and see if the files are re-coped from onsite or if only the meta data is adjusted which is what we want.

Comment: Our test determined Azure sync deletes the files in the Azure share and then uploads the current version from the server.  Seeding using the download option in Storage Explorer is useless for this task.  I'm not sure if AZCopy would work but I've spent too much time on this and since there are no answers here or on r/Azure, I have to move forward and upload from scratch which is disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible AFAIK

Our test determined Azure sync deletes the files in the Azure share and then uploads the current version from the server. Seeding using the download option in Storage Explorer is useless for this task. I'm not sure if AZCopy would work but I've spent too much time on this and since there are no answers here or on r/Azure, I have to move forward and upload from scratch which is disappointing.